# System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] instead of data

Tags: c#, html, sql, linq, chart.js

I am trying to retrieve all different months from a table in a database, but it keeps on giving me `System.Collections.Generic.List1[System.String]` in text on the front-end instead of the data.

```
var months = _db.Users.ToList().Select(o => o.dt_created.ToString("MMMM")).ToList();
ViewBag.Months = months;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is giving you where?

Comment: Oh, on the front-end in a text.

Comment: This is an important info. Much more, you need to exactly specify which front end.

Comment: It's giving you a list. You need a loop to read the items and display them.

Comment: The default string representation for an object (such as a `List<T>` for example) is the type name.  You'd need to specify how you want to translate that object into a string, either in this code or in the view.

Comment: @Casey, not necessarily. E.g. WPF can do this for you.

Comment: It is solved. Thanks all

Comment: You are using a ToList() . What exactly you expected as return?

Comment: Actually, it now displays the data in one text row, but I wanted to display it on the view as a list in JavaScript. Let me change the question a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ViewBag.Months = months;
```

The above code, the months is a list so how are you dispaying it in the UI, you need to join the list to show it as a string

```
ViewBag.Months = string.Join(", ", months);
```